# Adding a user to POSIX or "memberOf" groups in OpenLDAP

Tags: python, ldap3

I'm using Python `ldap3` module to work with an OpenLDAP server. I've been able to query, and add, users to an OU, but can't figure how to add users to groups (both POSIX and memberOf/groupOfNames overlay).  I found an Active Directory "way" of doing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609358/ldap3-python-add-user-to-group?rq=1) but how do I adapt that example for OpenLDAP? Not even sure `from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM` is a thing on Linux.

Trying the code below. User is added to the directory, but adding to the *POSIX* group `ldap-users` fails with a cascade of errors but this looks like the culprit. Not sure what I have messed up with the objectClass attributes:

```
LDAPInvalidAttributeSyntaxResult - 21 - invalidAttributeSyntax - None - objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

I thought I'd leave the *POSIX* groups for later and try the *memberOf* overlay (adding user to the `admins` *groupOfNames* object) but I'm stuck on that one with

```
ImportError: No module named 'ldap3.modlist'
```

Not sure why module `ldap3.modlist` isn't available. Shouldn't that be included with the Ubuntu/python `ldap3` package? Tried importing it explicitly.

```
   import ldap3.modlist as modlist
   import json
   import urllib.request
   from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
   import getopt, sys, logging
   from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
   ...
   # retrieve user details from HR database
   ldap_user = PersonFromHRDB(person_id)

   # fill in the template of attributes we need to give to the ldap server
   attributes = {   'givenName': ldap_user.givenName,
                           'sn': ldap_user.sn,
                  'displayName': ldap_user.displayName,
                          'uid': ldap_user.uidNumber,
                'homeDirectory': ldap_user.homeDirectory,
                 ...}

   # add user to DIT via their dn (dn:uid=user101,ou=people,dc=my,dc=dom)
   conn.add(ldap_user.dn, ['posixAccount', 'top', 'inetOrgPerson', 'shadowAccount'], attributes)

   # add user to a the 'ldap-users' POSIX group
   conn.add('cn=ldap-users,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=dom', {'memberUid': ldap_user.cn})

   # add user to 'admins' groupOfNames (memberOf overlay) object
   group_dn = 'cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=dom'
   conn.modify_s (group_dn, [ modlist.MOD_ADD, 'member', [ldap_user.dn]])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suspect you'll need to make use of the ldap [modify](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/modify.html) operation.

Comment: Code added. does `modify` work if the user doesn't currently exist? I suspect that operation is a bit like an LDIF file -- if the user doesn't exist, it's an `add`. If they do exist, it's a `modify` but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running across this, I had to add `MODIFY_ADD` to my ldap3 imports first. Then using `conn.modify()` as suggested by @larsks (modifed code below) to add the user to the openLDAP group.

Adding a user to a `POSIX` group vs. `memberOf` overlay is basically the same function but the attributes and user values are different. `POSIX` group uses the `memberUid` attribute and the user `CN` value whereas the `memberOf` overlay uses a `member` attribute along with the full `DN:` for the user.

Also, `conn.modify()` will hurl if the user already exists in the group and you try an add it, so, have to check first to see if the user is already there.

```
   import ldap3.modlist as modlist
   import json
   import urllib.request
   from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
   import getopt, sys, logging
   from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, MODIFY_REPLACE, MODIFY_ADD, MODIFY_DELETE

   ...
   # retrieve user details from HR database
   ldap_user = PersonFromHRDB(person_id)

   # fill in the template of attributes we need to give to the ldap server
   attributes = {   'givenName': ldap_user.givenName,
                           'sn': ldap_user.sn,
                  'displayName': ldap_user.displayName,
                          'uid': ldap_user.uidNumber,
                'homeDirectory': ldap_user.homeDirectory,
                 ...}

   # add user to DIT via their dn (dn:uid=user101,ou=people,dc=my,dc=dom)
   conn.add(ldap_user.dn, ['posixAccount', 'top', 'inetOrgPerson', 'shadowAccount'], attributes)

   group_dn = 'cn=ldap-users,ou=groups,dc=my,dc=dom'
   # default to POSIX attributes/values
   attribute = 'memberUid'
   user_value = ldap_user.cn

   if my_userExistsInGroup (ldap_user, group_dn) is False:
      # adjust for memberOf
      if my_isPosixGroup (group_dn) is False:
         attribute = 'member'
         user_value = ldap_user.dn

      conn.modify(group_dn, {attribute: [(MODIFY_ADD, [user_value])]})
```